# why we need to store millions of records in memory using some data structure while data can be stored in database?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

I have a very basic question, if we talk about millions of records to be manipulated, then why we need to store millions of records in memory? whatever record we need we can fetch from database and do manipulation in memory using some data structures and update back to database.

Comment: Because memory is fast and database is slow. But don't fool yourself, even to store records in the database you have to use some sort of data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give one example.

At work we work with language learning, so enormous data sets of words and phrases. (*hundreds of thousands of words, though it could easily reach the millions as time goes on*)

Good use of Data Structures are crucial to a successful application. Like @Juan Lopes said, keeping everything in databases is slow, and impractical. What happens if I need to manipulate multiple values or run an algorithm on a data set? I need to retrieve that data from my database first in order to to do this.

An argument can be made that algorithms can be added to the database then to solve this problem. More often then not however, you will not have ownership of the database, or you will consume data that you do not have permission to modify the server code for.

Also depending on which data structures you use you can save large amounts of time! Take the map/dictionary. By doing a O(n) pass on the data to create a map, I now am able to access any of the data in O(1) time if I know the key I'm looking for, Running a database query will rarely produce such fast results, also in modern applications often times the database is on a server far away from your program, and the time to retrieve the data is compounded with that of an HTTP request, which could very well take 10x the time to run the query itself.

In the end, there is a good reason that data structures are a fundamental part of any good programmers toolbox and why they teach it so vigorously in universities.

Comment: you have given best example of dictionary to explain. Thank you so much for quick response! :)